# Is division by zero considered error or failure?

Tags: error-handling, compiler-errors, syntax-error, runtime-error

When my program stops working due to division by 0 then is it considered error or failure?

Error is called when a human action produces an incorrect result. Failure is when we get different result than expected. I'm just wondering if the unexpected stop from program is a error by human or failure of the program?

Answer (score 0):

It is considere as an error. Or we can also called this an exception. And if u dont want to  prevent this u can use exception handling.
Depending on the programming environment and the type of number (e.g. floating point, integer) being divided by zero, it may generate positive or negative infinity, generate an exception, generate an error message, cause the program to terminate.

Answer (score -1):

It is a type of failure when it is in compile time but it is an error because usually this type of an error occur when the program is compiled and then executed